# Someone knows about online labs?

Tags: penetration-test, security-theater

I'm looking for an online training lab for pentesting/hacking and security.

I've found one at [hacking-lab](http://www.hacking-lab.com) but it's seems troublesome to work with and it has some issues on VPN server authentication.

Someone knows about something similar?

Or something like **[Hackademic RTB1](http://ghostinthelab.wordpress.com/2011/09/06/hackademic-rtb1-root-this-box/) and RTB2**?

I wish for more resources to learn with.

thx in advance.

Comment: Thx all. Well My Q is marked as off-topic. 
It's a difficult world for the newbie!! :).
I'm just searching for what I've to learn in the cyber-security world.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few different kind of labs available. There are ones you can construct yourself in VM's such as [Vulnhub](http://vulnhub.com/) and they have a lot of links to good resources there. Another site i can recommend with good resources is [Pentesterlab](https://www.pentesterlab.com/), i tend to steer clear of the online sites such as hackme so can't give much as to online but hope these help.

Answer (score 1):

https://microcorruption.com/ is a very interesting hack challenge. Try [googling](https://www.google.co.nz/search?q=hack%20challenge&oq=hack%20challenge&) for "hack challenge", there's plenty of other websites around.

If you want to do your own stuff (e.g. set up a vulnerable host or machine) you can either use a VM (free windows VMs available from microsoft at http://modern.ie) or get a free EC2 instance from amazon.

Answer (score 1):

Also search for "wargames" if you want to learn how to exploit vulnerabilities. 
Here is an example: http://smashthestack.org

Answer (score 0):

As you have stated that you need some online labs for Penetration Testing and learning Hacking.Here is a really exhaustive list of vulnerable VMs, Web Apps etc.You can use these VM's and easily learn the Penetration Testing.

http://www.amanhardikar.com/mindmaps/Practice.html

But as these list is too exhaustive ,i would advice you to go with OWASP BWA. https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Broken_Web_Applications_Project
It Contain's almost the most updated Vulnerable WebApps